# Complex elementwise comparison by columns in R

Tags: arrays, r, loops

I'd like to compare subjects by two column entries: Value and Length. 
The subject will be compared with all other subjects in the data frame; they will receive a -1 for each subject that has a higher value in the 'Length' column. If they have a higher value for the entry in the 'Length' column they will receive a +1. If their value is equal to another subject's value in the 'Length' column, their value in the 'Value' column will be compared (+1 if their entry is greater; 0 if the value is equal; and -1 if their value is less). The entry in the new column 'Value2' would be the sum of the +1, 0, or -1 values from the comparisons.

I have written something in base R but it doesn't seem to work.

```
             Value        Length
Subject1     2            0
Subject2     0            1
Subject3     5            1
Subject4     4            5
Subject5     4            5
Subject6     7            6
Subject7     9            8


for(i in 1:length(x)){
   for(j in 1:length(x)){
      if(i != j){
         w = z[c(-i), ]
         if(w$length[i] < w$length[j]){ value2[i] = value2[i] -1   }

         if(w$length[i] > w$length[j]){ value2[i] = value2[i} + 1  }

         if(w$length[i] == w$length[j]){
            if(w$value[i] < w$value[j]){ value2[i] = value2[i] - 1 }
            if(w$value[i] > w$value[j]){ value2[i] = value2[i] + 1 }

            if(w$value[i] == w$value[j]){ value2[i] = value2[i] }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Expected output:

```
            Value        Length      Value2
Subject1     2            0          -6
Subject2     0            1          -4
Subject3     5            1          -2          
Subject4     4            5          +1
Subject5     4            5          +1
Subject6     7            6          +4
Subject7     9            8          +6
```

Comment: What is the expected output for your example input?

Comment: I suspect you simply need to start with `DF[order(DF$Length, DF$value]` and the task can be easily done with a vectorized approach.

Comment: It even appears that `order(DF$Length, DF$value)` is your result (barring some transformation).

Comment: @Roland I think you are mostly correct; however, I need to compute the 'Value2' column which has to take equal values of 'Length' and 'Value' in to account. I will update the initial data frame to include an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you want to use `rank` and its tie-breaking but with two instead of one vector as input. The easiest solution would be to combine these two vectors. E.g., if you only have integers, you can do this:

```
res <- DF$Length + DF$Value/(max(DF$Value) + 1)
#[1] 0.2 1.0 1.5 5.4 5.4 6.7 8.9
res <- rank(res)
#[1] 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.5 4.5 6.0 7.0
res <- c(scale(res * 2, scale = FALSE)) #transformation of ranks
#[1] -6 -4 -2  1  1  4  6
```

Comment: I am absolutely flabbergasted. Why does that even work?

Comment: sorry, I should have been more explicit. I can easily examine the intermediate results. I am more curious how you could make the leap from the question's description to using the rank.

Comment: You basically can follow my thoughts if you read the comments under the question. I just googled how one would use `order` with different handling of ties and found an SO answer with `rank`.

Answer (score 1):

The first element, comparing lengths, can be easily done using vectorized operations:

```
sum(length[i] > length) - sum(length[i] < length)
```

But doesn't that include comparing the subject to itself? No, because it will never be counted as `length[i] > length[i] == 0`.

For the second element, we subset the value-column to those cases where the subject's value is equal to the other's length:

```
sum(value[i] > value[length == length[i]]) - sum(value[i] < value[length == length[i]])
```

These loop-operations in R are easier done with the `*apply`-family of functions. Observe:

```
df <- read.table(text = '             Value        Length
Subject1     2            0
Subject2     0            1
Subject3     5            1
Subject4     4            5
Subject5     4            5
Subject6     7            6
Subject7     9            8', as.is=TRUE)

# Estimate separately to verify correctishness
apply(df, 1, function(s) {
  sum(s[2] > df$Length) - sum(s[2] < df$Length)
})
# Subject1 Subject2 Subject3 Subject4 Subject5 Subject6 Subject7 
#   -6       -3       -3        1        1        4        6 
apply(df, 1, function(s) {
  sum(s[1] > df$Value[df$Length == s[2]]) - sum(s[1] < df$Value[df$Length == s[2]])
})
# Subject1 Subject2 Subject3 Subject4 Subject5 Subject6 Subject7 
#    0       -1        1        0        0        0        0 

# combine
apply(df, 1, function(s) {
  v1 <- sum(s[2] > df$Length) - sum(s[2] < df$Length)
  v2 <- sum(s[1] > df$Value[df$Length == s[2]]) - sum(s[1] < df$Value[df$Length == s[2]])
  v1 + v2
})
# Subject1 Subject2 Subject3 Subject4 Subject5 Subject6 Subject7 
#   -6       -4       -2        1        1        4        6
```

But I kinda like @Roland's answer, although I don't quite understand it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Could also do:

```
transform(df,
          Value2 = sapply(1:nrow(df), 
                          function(x) sum(ifelse(Length[x] != Length[-x], Length[x] < Length[-x], Value[x] < Value[-x])) * -1 +
                            sum(ifelse(Length[x] != Length[-x], Length[x] > Length[-x], Value[x] > Value[-x]))
          )
)
```

Output:

```
   Subject Value Length Value2
1 Subject1     2      0     -6
2 Subject2     0      1     -4
3 Subject3     5      1     -2
4 Subject4     4      5      1
5 Subject5     4      5      1
6 Subject6     7      6      4
7 Subject7     9      8      6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternatives.  No packages are used.

**1)** Create a function `fun` to compute `value2` for row `i` and then apply it to each row.  For row `i` it computes the sum of the signs of the the relevant differences.  This uses no packages and is a relatively straight forward vectorization of the problem.

```
fun <- function(i, data) with(data, {
  dL <- Length[i] - Length[-i]
  sum(sign(ifelse(dL == 0, Value[i] - Value[-i], dL)))
})
transform(DF, value2 = sapply(1:nrow(DF), fun, DF))
```

giving:

```
         Value Length value2
Subject1     2      0     -6
Subject2     0      1     -4
Subject3     5      1     -2
Subject4     4      5      1
Subject5     4      5      1
Subject6     7      6      4
Subject7     9      8      6
```

**2)** A variation would be to write `fun` like this:

```
fun <- function(i, data) with(data, {
  dL <- Length[i] - Length[-i]
  sum(sign((dL == 0) * (Value[i] - Value[-i]) + dL))
})
transform(DF, value2 = sapply(1:nrow(DF), fun, DF))
```

**3)** At the possible expense of clarity, we could further vectorize using `outer` giving this alternative:

```
outL <- outer(DF$Length, DF$Length, "-")
outV <- outer(DF$Value, DF$Value, "-")
transform(DF, value2 = rowSums(sign(ifelse(outL == 0, outV, outL))))
```

or the last line could be shortened further to:

```
transform(DF, value2 = rowSums(sign((outL == 0) * outV + outL)))
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
DF <-
structure(list(Value = c(2L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 9L), Length = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Subject1", 
"Subject2", "Subject3", "Subject4", "Subject5", "Subject6", "Subject7"
))
```